# Sometime my function take a looong time to execute

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have tried for the 1st time `Azure Function`, besides a couple of problems where I found a workaround, it was quite easy to develop and publish my function to Azure. I even tried preview features like durable entities and it works great, I am enthusiast.

However, I had some concerns with the timings. My function is http triggered, it's called by another application. Most of the time execution time is ~1sec which is great. Sometimes, I don't know why it takes up to 30 secs to execute the same function. Is this normal? Maybe some cold start? Or it's me doing something wrong? I am a newbie so I'd like the experts opinion. I am using consumption plan in w. Europe.

Unfortunately for this application anything > 4 sec is not acceptable because it will cause an error in the caller reflected in turn to the end user.

Here you can se a screen capture of logs with timings, look at the bottom what crazy slow times.

Any way to ensure timing always within 4 secs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This much variation would not be expected with cold start. Generally cold start is about 2-5 seconds and should only happen if a long period of no invocations. Also the measurement here is just execution time, and doesn’t include startup time. I’d recommend looking into logs and adding traces to see if there’s a line of code it’s hanging on.

Comment: @jeffholan I agree, it is totally worth to check the whole scenario not just what I have mentioned in my answer. The slowness might be related also for the code part. Other than that do you have an exact number when (just like in minutes) the the serverless solution needs to be warmed up again? I did not find yet any reference about that.

Comment: 15 minutes is how long till it spins down

Comment: @jeffhollan thanks for the clarification, it's reassuring knowing cold start is 2-5 sec. BTW the problem magically disappeared I have tried hundreds times it's always blazing fast. I tried also after 12 hours inactivity: it's fast as a VM always on. I am new to AzFunc. so I need to study more monitoring and debug options, will surely do. I should say I'm using beta features, entity func. that are single thread locked and beta of course. Maybe one entity was locked and causing delay..I found also bugs already posted on GH Chris & team investiganting.Anyway I love durable func now also stateful!

Comment: Awesome! Let us know if any other issues pop up

Answer (score 0):

First step is to understand what happens once you hit one `Azure Function` endpoint, step by step:

1. Azure must allocate your application to a server with capacity,
2. The Functions runtime must then start up on that server,
3. Your code then needs to execute.

> I don't know why it takes up to 30 secs to execute the same function. Is this normal? Maybe some cold start?

I think the answer is related to cold start, the following image represents what happens when you trigger a function app's endpoint (Source: [Understanding serverless cold start](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/?ref=msdn)):

[image]

I have similar issues once using Consumption plan. A dedicated plan might be a solution for your case, half minute to warm up an endpoint is pretty bad. To keep the function warm, you have a chance to use Premium plan which promises the following:

> When you're using the Premium plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are added and removed based on the number of incoming events just like the Consumption plan. Premium plan supports the following features: **Perpetually warm instances to avoid any cold start**

You can read about this further: [Premium plan (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan)

**Additional information:**

Be careful with the mentioned option because the pricing might be different based on the following:

> Instead of billing per execution and memory consumed, billing for the Premium plan is based on the number of core seconds, execution time, and memory used across needed and reserved instances. At least one instance must be warm at all times. This means that there is a fixed monthly cost per active plan, regardless of the number of executions.

I would consider at least for testing purposes the above mentioned option, I hope the answer helps and gives you the idea why you have slow startup.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I started from zero couple of days ago, good to know all these options are available. However I guess I can use the consumption plan, now it's blazing fast since almost 2 days. Should I ensure max speed to a customer I will consider more expensive plans. Love Az functions, perfect to get started with cloud native apps without intimidating upfront costs.